# How do I enforce host based security with SslStream?

Tags: c#, ssl, certificate, sslstream

Suppose I want to do host-based-security similar to HTTPS. What is the canonical validation code to verify that the server certificate matches the hostname and the certificate chain is valid when I open my SslStream connection?

Comment: Ok I found the answer.... It's a bit 'duh'. Someone want to post before I do? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's just too easy (RTFD@me!). Let the framework do all that tricky authentication for you:

await sslStream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync(hostname);